# Typescript - Check combinations of parameters are null

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I wrote this function that construct an object based if some values are null or not.

```
protected temporalFilter({ range }: Filter): W {
    const temporalKey = ['created', 'bootedSince', 'firstComunication'];
    if (temporalKey.includes(range.key)) {
      if (range.from && !range.to) {
        return {
          [range.from as keyof T]: { gte: range.from }
        } as unknown as W;
      }
      else if (!range.from && range.to) {
        return {
          [range.to as keyof T]: { lte: range.to }
        } as unknown as W;
      }
      else if (range.from && range.to) {
        return {
          AND: [
            { [range.key as keyof T]: { lte: range.to } },
            { [range.key as keyof T]: { gte: range.from } }
          ]
        } as unknown as W;
      }
      else return {} as unknown as W;
    }
    else return null;
  }
```

But, there is a compact way to do that or some refactoring that can I do?

Comment: pls share reproducable example. Where did you get `Filter`. I assume it is from elastic search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most compact yet readable form I can think of:

```
temporalFilter({range}: Filter): W {
  if (['created', 'bootedSince', 'firstComunication'].includes(range.key)) {
    const f = range.from ? { [range.from]: {gte: range.from} } : undefined;
    const t = range.to ? { [range.to]: {lte: range.to} } : undefined;
    return ((f && t) ? { AND: [f, t] } : (f || t)) as unknown as W;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

*I suggest you fix your typing; the usage of so many `unknown` in a single function suggests poor typing. Furthermore, this `{ [range.from]: {gte: range.from} }` it is not wrong, but it is strange to have the same value as filtering condition and as key, perhaps you meant `{ [range.key]: {gte: range.from} }`*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I put `as unknow as W` because I have this error `the type is not assignable to W`. How can I resolve?

Comment: The error you are getting is due to problems within `Filter` and `W`if you can provide the complete context (eg `Filter` definition and what `W` is), i can address you better.

Comment: Btw, I edited my answer to address your current typing issues in the same way you did

Comment: W is a type generated from `Prisma` and `Filter` as defined as follow: `export type Filter = {
  key?: any,
  field?: any,
  range?: {
    key?: any,
    from?: any,
    to?: any,
  },
};`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work right? I did not test this, just a thought on how to use conditional spreading:

```
 return {
     ...(!!range.from && {[range.from]: {gte: range.from}}),
     ...(!!range.to && {[range.to]: {lte: range.to}})
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't cover for the `null` case, write a complete answer. You have some typos, you closed the parentheses with brackets, other than that, i like alot your solution so far.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by `null` case, the `includes` condition can be tested separately and return `null` when necessary. Is there some other case I am missing? @darklightcode